# Appgyver and in app purchase / billing

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, appgyver

I currently use Appgyver platform to make an app and I would like to implement in-app purchases. I was wondering if anyone has already done this. Unfortunately, the documentation is quite poor and this functionality is not available in the appgyver add-ons.

Any ideas will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with using custom plugins with Appgyver? [Docs here](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/plugins/configuring-custom-plugins/) and a forum post about In-app purchases is [here](http://community.appgyver.com/t/im-really-interested-in-the-in-app-purchase-add-on-do-you-guys-have-an-eta/4199).